# R package development, Possible to create submaps within \R directory?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a R package. Now I've used roxygen and devtools to help create all necessary files and it's working.

Among others I have the maps **/man , /R, /tests**. Now I would like to create some subfolders in /R directory, but once I do this and move any scripts inside I get an **Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports)** when trying to rebuild the package.

Can I only have script files directly within /R subdirectory, and is there any solution to this other than putting the script files in other maps one level up? (such as old scripts that one may use in the future)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the `/R` subdirectory can only contain R code files https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories

Comment: you mean level down? all directories in `/inst` are copied recursively to top level when building a package `list.dirs(system.file(package = 'ggplot2'))`

Comment: @uncool you should also use standard nomenclature. they are _directories_ (singular: _directory_).

Comment: I'd rather store those stale old scripts in *git* and not in the `R` directory, but if you insist on storing wrong files in wrong folders, `.Rbuildignore` might be your friend :)